# Como executar mais rápido um código que calcula a quantidade de dígitos do fatorial de um número?

Tags: python, matemática

O código deve imprimir quantos dígitos tem o fatorial de N.

Estou tentando realizar um desafio simples de fatorial no site URI e quando submeto o código a resposta é sempre "Time limit exceeded", o limite é 1.00s e está dando 2.00s. Já pesquisei sobre o problema e tentei modificar o código para ficar mais rápido, porém o erro se repete. Segue os códigos que submeti:

```py
N = int(input())
for i in range(1, N):
  N = (i * N)
print(len(str(N)))
```

Este também:

```py
import math
N = input()
print(len(str(math.factorial(int(N)))))
```

Tentei usar o `stdout.write` mas deu "Presentation Error" apesar de ter executado também em 2.00s

```py
import math
from sys import stdin, stdout
N = int(input())
for i in range(1, N):
  N = N * i
  stdout.flush()
N = len(str(N))
stdout.write(str(N))
```

```py
import math
from sys import stdin, stdout
N = int(input())
for i in range(1, N):
  N = N * i
  stdout.flush()
N = len(str(math.factorial(N)))
stdout.write(str(N))
```

Gostaria de dicas de qual caminho seguir para melhor o tempo de execução e por que estas não deram certo.

Comment: Você mencionou o tempo gasto, mas não mencionou para qual valor de `N` esse tempo foi calculado. Quais os valores de `N` que você usou nos seus testes ?

Comment: @Lacobus Esse é um desafio do URI. Normalmente, o URI faz testes com um monte de entradas diferentes, e muitas delas são secretas para evitar que os algoritmos sejam desenvolvidos de forma a tentar burlá-las. Muitas das entradas que tipicamente explodem algoritmos feitos por iniciantes são coisas monstruosas e/ou números astronômicos.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta, os casos de testes são para 0 < N <= 10^8

Comment: Vey, pergunta veya e n deve precisar mais, mas `n! = Gamma(n+1)` e `Digits(i) = floor(log10(i))+1 = floor(log10(exp(1))*ln(i))+1 ~ floor(0.43429448190325182765*ln(i))+1`, portanto `Digits(n!) ~ floor(0.43429448190325182765*ln( Gamma(n+1) ))+1`. Função em python que calcula `ln(Gamma())` é `scipy.special.gammaln`.

Comment: Ou seja, simplesmente da import de `math` e `scipy.special` e usa a expressão `math.floor( 1+0.43429448190325182765*scipy.special.gammaln(N+1) )` ou mesmo (pra não precisar calcular a constante) `math.floor( 1+math.log10( math.exp(1) )*scipy.special.gammaln(N+1) )`. É cálculo bem rápido.

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que o fatorial cresce muito rápido, e em pouco tempo você estará multiplicando números enormes, o que é bem demorado. Só para ter uma ideia, o fatorial de 10<sup>8</sup> (que é o [limite máximo que você indicou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445568/como-executar-mais-r%C3%A1pido-um-c%C3%B3digo-que-calcula-a-quantidade-de-d%C3%ADgitos-do-fator/445603#comment856398_445568)) é um número com mais de 750 milhões de dígitos. Manipular números dessa grandeza não tem como ser rápido...

Então uma alternativa é calcular a quantidade de dígitos do fatorial, mas sem precisar calcular o valor do fatorial.

Uma forma de obter a quantidade de dígitos de um número é [calcular o logaritmo na base 10, arredondar para baixo e somar 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231742).

Outro detalhe é que o log<sub>10</sub>(a * b) é igual a log<sub>10</sub>(a) + log<sub>10</sub>(b).

E como o fatorial de N é a multiplicação de todos os números inteiros entre 1 e N, podemos calcular o log<sub>10</sub>(N!) somando os logs de todos os números entre 1 e N. Ou seja:

- log<sub>10</sub>(N!) é o mesmo que log<sub>10</sub>(1 * 2 * 3 * ... * N)
- que por sua vez é o mesmo que log<sub>10</sub>(1) + log<sub>10</sub>(2) + log<sub>10</sub>(3) + ... + log<sub>10</sub>(N)

Então basta somar os logs de todos os números de 1 a N, arredondar para baixo e somar 1, para obter a quantidade de dígitos de N! (sem precisar calcular o valor do fatorial).

Ficaria assim:

```
from math import floor, log10

n = int(input())

res = 0
for i in range(1, n + 1):
  res += log10(i)

print(floor(res) + 1)
```

Ou ainda:

```
print(floor(sum(map(log10, range(1, n + 1)))) + 1)
```

Não testei no URI online, mas fiz um [pequeno teste](https://ideone.com/ExMzxt) no qual as duas opções acima se mostraram bem mais rápidas que calcular o fatorial:

```
from math import floor, log10, factorial
from timeit import repeat

def log(n):
  res = 0
  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    res += log10(i)

  return floor(res) + 1

def log2(n):
  return floor(sum(map(log10, range(1, n + 1)))) + 1

def fact(n):
  return floor(log10(factorial(n))) + 1 

n = 200000
x = 1
r = 3
print (repeat ('log(n)', repeat=r, number=x, globals=globals()))
print (repeat ('log2(n)', repeat=r, number=x, globals=globals()))
print (repeat ('fact(n)', repeat=r, number=x, globals=globals()))
```

E quanto maior o N, maior a diferença entre as abordagens.

E faz sentido. Ao calcular o fatorial, você está multiplicando números cada vez maiores, enquanto que no método dos logaritmos estamos somando números pequenos (tudo bem que temos que calcular o logaritmo de todos os números, mas ainda sim compensa e é mais rápido).

Comment: Se eu não tivesse lido a sua resposta eu teria respondido errado. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a [fórmula de Kamenetsky](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19170/how-good-is-kamenetskys-formula-for-the-number-of-digits-in-n-factorial) para se calcular a quantidade de digitos contidos no fatorial de `N`, veja só:

```
def kamenetsky(n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    x = (n * log10(n / e)) + (log10(2 * pi * n) / 2.0)
    return floor(x) + 1
```

Para efeito de comparação dos algoritmos testados, sugiro a implementação de uma função capaz de mensurar o tempo de processamento gasto por cada um deles:

```
from timeit import default_timer

def teste( func, n, cont=1000 ):
    inicio = default_timer()
    for i in range(cont):
        func(n)
    fim = default_timer()
    total = fim - inicio
    return (total / cont) * (10**6) # Tempo em microsegundos
```

Testando:

```
from math import log10, floor, factorial, pi, e
from timeit import default_timer

def teste( func, n, cont=1000 ):
    inicio = default_timer()
    for i in range(cont):
        func(n)
    fim = default_timer()
    total = fim - inicio
    return (total / cont) * (10**6)

def f1(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        n = i * n
    return len(str(n))

def f2(n):
    n = factorial(n)
    return len(str(n))

def f3(n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    x = (n * log10(n / e) + log10(2 * pi * n) / 2.0)
    return floor(x) + 1

N = 100
print('f1(): {:.3f} uS'.format(teste(f1, N)))
print('f2(): {:.3f} uS'.format(teste(f2, N)))
print('f3(): {:.3f} uS'.format(teste(f3, N)))
```

Saída:

```
f1(): 7.629 uS
f2(): 1.796 uS
f3(): 0.678 uS
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta questão se refere ao problema de número **"3096"**, cujo título é **"overflow"**, disponibilizado por **URI Online Judge** (maratona online de programação).

[Veja aqui](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/3096) a íntegra do enunciado.

A questão enfatiza que, em muitos casos onde é necessário calcular o fatorial de um número, cujo resultado possui um número `muito grande` de algarismos, possivelmente pode resultar em um [overflow](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transbordamento_de_dados).

Observe que a questão diz que o programa deve suportar valores `N`, tais que,  `1<= N <= 10^8`, isto é, deve suportar valores entre `1` e `100000000`. Agora, imagine o quanto de recursos computacionais um programa usaria se tivesse de calcular o fatorial de `100000000`?

Pra começar, o `número total de dígitos` de `100000000!` é `756570557`. Para melhorar a legibilidade podemos dividir em milhares e deixa-lo da seguinte forma `756.570.557`,ou seja, o número total de dígitos resultante do fatorial de `100.000.000` é `setecentos e cinquenta e seis milhões, quinhentos e setenta mil, quinhentos e cinquenta e sete`.

Como é muito `demorado` se obter o valor correto para fatoriais de `grandes` valores, o problema nos pede para calcular `apenas` o número de dígitos do possível fatorial.

Na matemática, podemos sim, calcular o número de dígitos do resultado do fatorial sem mesmo ter calculado o fatorial desse número. Para isso basta utilizar a fórmula de [Kamenetsky](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19170/how-good-is-kamenetskys-formula-for-the-number-of-digits-in-n-factorial).

Para implementarmos esta fórmula corretamente na questão do Uri, com todas as restrições que nos é enfatizada, devemos escrever o seguinte código...

```
from math import log10, e, pi, floor

n = int(input())

num_digitos = floor((n * log10(n / e)) + (log10(2 * pi * n) / 2.0)) + 1
print('{}'.format(num_digitos))
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/wvxzquxj-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que, quando executamos este programa, a tela do console fica `limpa`, aguardando a digitação do valor de `N`. Após digitarmos o valor de `N` e, em seguida, pressionarmos `Enter`, o programa conclui a tarefa.

Este código já foi `testado`, `submetido` e devidamente `aprovado`, na maratona que me referir no início do poste, sob linguagem de programação `Python 3`.

Só para constar, este programa levou apenas `0.028 s` para ser executado no site `URI`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode computar o fatorial de um número usando a [Função Gamma de Ramanujan](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/09/25/ramanujans-factorial-approximation/) que é semelhante ao [Gamma de Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), porém é mais precisa:

[image: função Gamma de Ramanujan]

Função Gamma ou Γ é a extensão da função factorial para o conjunto dos números reais e complexos. A função Gamma é definida para todos os complexos exceto os inteiros negativos.

Como o domínio estabelecido pelo AP [0, 10⁸⁰] é de extensão maior que [`sys.float_info.max`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) usei a biblioteca [Mpmath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/) que é uma biblioteca Python para aritmética de ponto flutuante de precisão arbitrária.

A implementação para computar o a quantidade de dígitos de um fatorial fica assim:

```
#No comentário foi definido o domínio [0, 10 ^ 80] então usei mpmath 
from mpmath import log10, pi, e, sqrt

def gamma(x):
  return int(log10(sqrt(pi)*(x/e)**x * (((8*x + 4)*x + 1)*x + 1/30.)**(1./6.))) + 1
```

Teste no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/RelievedJaggedLogins

Answer (score -5):

Manda a pergunta se esse código não lhe ajudar.

```
num = int(input('Numero: '))
for i in range(1, num):
  num = i * num
#Mostrando o fatorial do numero digitado
print(num)
#Essa varivel converte o valor int para string
converte = str(num)
#Aqui ele mostra o tamanho da string
print(len(converte))
```

Comment: É o primeiro que testei, só que com nomes de variáveis diferentes.